# MongoDB $lookup array of lookup field values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, lookup

I'm using MongoDB, and I tried to do it with many pipeline steps but I couldn't find a way.

I have a players collection, each player contains an items array

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fba17c1c4566e57fafdcd7e"),
    "username": "moshe",
    "items": [ 
        "5fbb5ab778045a985690b5fc",
        "5fbb5ab778045a985690b5fd"
    ]
}
```

I have an items collection where there is more information about each item in the player items array.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fbb5ab778045a985690b5fc"),
    "name": "Axe",
    "damage": 4,
    "defense": 6
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fbb5ab778045a985690b5fd"),
    "name": "Demo",
    "damage": 1,
    "defense": 1
}
```

My goal is to have a player document with all the information about the item inside his items array, so it will look like that:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5fba17c1c4566e57fafdcd7e"),
    "username": "moshe",
    "items": [ 
        "5fbb5ab778045a985690b5fc",
        "5fbb5ab778045a985690b5fd"
    ],
    "itemNames": [
        "Axe",
        "Demo"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `$lookup` with a pipeline to overcome the difference between `ObjectId` and `string`:

```
db.players.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "items",
      let: {items: {$ifNull: ["$items", []]}},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {$in: [{$toString: "$_id"}, "$$items"]}}},
        {$project: {name: 1, _id: 0}}
      ],
      as: "itemNames"
    }
  },
  {$set: {itemNames: {$map: {input: "$itemNames", in: "$$this.name"}}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8IwUaMMwEE5)

- Updated with `$ifNull` for cases of no `items` field, as mentioned on the comments.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have one more question, instead of player item object, i just need only name from play item object, then how i can do that?

Comment: {
    "_id": ObjectId("5fba17c1c4566e57fafdcd7e"),
    "username": "moshe",
    "items": [
        {
            "Axe",
            "Demo"
    ]
}

Comment: You can do it like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iCIBwWYSQo7)

Comment: some record havent items value its null value in {
      "_id": ObjectId("5fba17c1c4566e57fafdcd7e"),
      "username": "moshe",
      "items": null
    }

Comment: its throwing below error query failed: (Location40081) PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: null

Comment: See it with `$ifNull` [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qYNOgSHkD02)

Comment: you did blank array instead of null, please set as null and test again it will throw an error

Comment: $ifNull is working fine thank you

Comment: is it possible to return that names in new field like itemNames: ["Axes", "Demo"], i have updated question

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. Please don't update a question after it has answers, you can ask a new one if needed